# How can I run a video stream backwards in Sony Vegas Studio?

Tags: video-editing, sony-vegas

How do I flip a video stream, making it effectively appear to run backwards?

For example, I've got a 6 second video stream.  I cut it at 2, 4, 6, so I've got now 3 seperate streams with 2 seconds each.

- 1-2 ; 3-4; 5-6 -> That's how it'll be displayed normally.

Now what I want to do in Sony Vegas is to copy/paste and flip a selected stream. Let say:

- 1-2; 3-4; 3'-4'; 5-6 -> The second *3-4* is copy/pasted; now I've got a video stream with 8 seconds.

Now I want to flip this copy pasted making it effectively run backwards.

- 1-2; 3-4; 4'-3'; 5-6.

The idea is I want something like a movie, it goes, and goes and goes, then a text appears "WAIT! What just happend?", then the movie goes back to second 3.

- 1-2-3-4-'WAIT! What just happened?'-4-3-4-5-6.

I hope you get what I want to do in Sony Vegas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the timeline, right-click on the 4'-3' clip that you want to reverse and select "Reverse" from the context menu.

Comment: o boy, I must've been pretty blind. That's embarasing!

Thanks!

Comment: To be fair, I think it's in a counter-intuitive place. You kind of expect it to be a video effect that's dropped on the clip...